# Call dll class function

Tags: visual-c++

I have dll that contains class. I need to create object of that class and call it's methods in my console application. What is procedure of calling class dll in c++? How I should define dll in my code?

Answer (score 1):

A DLL should come with an h file and a lib file. To use the DLL you #include the h file and you link to the lib file. To do the linking go into the project properties, link section, and add the lib file to the "additional dependencies" setting.